# Using ROW_NUMBER() with a derived table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a table in which I am returning an ID and a DATEDIFF value:

```
SELECT        
    CTD_ITEM_ID, CTD_ASSIGNED_TO, 
    DATEDIFF(d, CTD_ASSIGNED_DATE, CTD_REVIEW_COMPLETED_DATE) AS DATE_DIFF
FROM            
    IRT_ITEM_TRACKING_DETAIL_TBL
ORDER BY 
    CTD_ITEM_ID, DATE_DIFF DESC
```

That results in many values of `date_diff` for identical `ctd_item_id`.

From this I wish to drive a table where on the largest `date_diff` is kept for each `ctd_item_id`. So, I should use `ROW_NUMBER()` - but I am not sure how to combine the creation of the value above (`date_diff`) with the `ROW_NUMBER()` capability.

I have tried many iterations of something like this:

```
WITH max_date_diffs AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        date_diffs.ctd_item_id, 
        date_diffs.date_diff 
    FROM   
        (SELECT 
             ctd_item_id, 
             DATEDIFF(d, ctd_assigned_date, ctd_review_complete_date) AS datediff 
         FROM   
             irt_item_tracking_detail_tbl) AS date_diffs
) 
SELECT   
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ctd_item_id (ORDER BY date_diff DESC) AS rownumber, 
    * 
FROM
    max_date_diffs
```

But I have not been able to get it to work.

EDIT:

This statement:

```
SELECT        
    CTD_ITEM_ID, CTD_ASSIGNED_TO, 
    MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, CTD_ASSIGNED_DATE, CTD_REVIEW_COMPLETED_DATE)) AS MAX_DATE_DIFF
FROM
    IRT_ITEM_TRACKING_DETAIL_TBL
GROUP BY 
    CTD_ITEM_ID, CTD_ASSIGNED_TO
ORDER BY 
    CTD_ITEM_ID, max_date_diff DESC
```

returns a table like this:

[image]

But I only want the rows that are highlighted in yellow, which is why I felt that on this table I would need to perform the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Your first query shouldn't work in any database, because the of incompatibility between the expressions and the `group by`.

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're missing `PARTITION BY ctd_item_id`.

Try:

```
SELECT ctd_item_id,
       ctd_assigned_to,
       max_date_diff
       FROM (SELECT ctd_item_id,
                    ctd_assigned_to,
                    max(datediff(day, ctd_assigned_date, ctd_review_completed_date)) max_date_diff,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ctd_item_id,
                                       ORDER BY max(datediff(day, ctd_assigned_date, ctd_review_completed_date)) DESC) rn
                    FROM irt_item_tracking_detail_tbl
                    GROUP BY ctd_item_id,
                             ctd_assigned_to) x
       WHERE rn = 1
       ORDER BY ctd_item_id ASC,
                max_date_diff DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT ctd_item_id, 
       MAX(DATEDIFF(DAY, ctd_assigned_date, ctd_review_completed_date)) AS MAX_DATE_DIFF
FROM irt_item_tracking_detail_tbl 
GROUP BY ctd_item_id 
ORDER BY max_date_diff ;
```

Comment: I have edited the question based on your answer to provide more detail.